# ReactJS/Javascript: State not updated on submit

Tags: java, reactjs, graphql-js

I added another input component, `endTime`, and followed the code for `startTime` but the input value for `endTime` is not being passed; only `startTime`.  So the input value for `startTime` is being passed but not the `endTime`.  Not sure why because I just replicated the code I did for `startTime` and applied it for `endTime`.

```
class Calendar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          startTime: '',//This will keep track of the date/time
          endTime:''
        };

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

      }

      handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        console.log(this.state.startTime);
        this.setState({
          startTime: new Date(document.getElementById("startTime").value).valueOf(),
          endTime: new Date(document.getElementById("endTime").value).valueOf()
        }, () => {
          this.props.data.refetch({//rerun the query using attribute 'timestamp'.  Assign the value of inputvalue, which is the current state after pressing the button
            startTime: this.state.startTime,
            endTime:this.state.endtTime
          });
          console.log(this.state.startTime);
          console.log(this.state.endTime);
        });
      };

      render() {

        console.log(this.props);
        return (
          <div className="Calendar">
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
              <label>Start Time</label>
              <input type="datetime-local" id="startTime" step="1" />              
            </form>

            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
              <label>End Time</label>
              <input type="datetime-local" id="endTime" step="1" />
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>

          </div>

        );
      }
};
export default graphql(getObjectsQuery, 
  { options: (ownProps) => { 
    console.log(ownProps.startTime); 
    return ({ variables: { startTime: ownProps.startTime,
                            endTime: ownProps.endTime
     } }) 
  } } )(Calendar);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already binding the function on the constructor you just need to pass the prop like this `<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>`

Comment: Tried it but it did  endTime is still undefined.

Comment: Did some more checking and found out endTime is updated with the input value. The problem now is that value is not being passed to the query, getObjectsQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. In `setState` `endtime` was spelled wrong.